# Creating a "clone" of an aspx website on the same server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm currently working on an aspx website. I want to create a "clone" of it, ie, run the same whole website in another folder, for eg, i want www.example.com to run in www.example.com/temp_site as well. Would creating a new folder temp_site and copying all the contents of my httpdocs folder into temp_site work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a **httpmodule** class to implement it. The following is the sample code

```
public class RidirectModule : IHttpModule
```

{

```
#region IHttpModule Members

public void Dispose()
{
    // Nothing to dispose
}

public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
}

#endregion


void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;            
    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
    {
        string query = context.Request.RawUrl;
        if (query.Contains("/temp_site"))
            context.Response.Redirect(query.Replace("/temp_site", "") );
    }       
}
```

}

Then adding the httpmodule in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an asp.net web application, your bin folders (where you have the dlls) may bring problems when you copy then entire content and put it in a sub folder. This leads you to have 2 bin directories with same dlls and you are going to face problems with that.

If you have the source code with you, why not create a temp folder in your solution and add the required files(asp.net) under that.You may skip copying the common files (images/css/js/user controls etc) and update the copied pages to use the existing ones.

If you dont have the source code, try copying all contents except the bin folder and keep it in the sub directory. You may update the links to your CSS file /Images (in the copied files )to refer the existing CSS/images/js files to avoid duplicate items and then delete the second copy of them (which we end up when we copied to the sub directory)

Comment: Yeah, it uses dlls in the bin folder. So how do you suggest I work around this?

Comment: I updated the answer. Try that and see what you get. Lets work on that from there

Comment: Find out where your bin folder resides. That should be your root. copy from there